# Vertical rotation of text inside div

Tags: html

I have a div which contains two lines but i want to make them show up as vertical.

This is how my div looks like

```
<div>
 Line One <br>Line Two
</div>
```

Is there a way to make text orientation inside the div vertical so that it appears like

```
L L
I I
N N
E E

O T
N W
E O
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css you can rotate text. but a few different:

```
<div style="-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);-o-transform: rotate(90deg);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);">
 Line One
</div>
```

Comment: this works well. Since i only have to deal with IE, i will use this.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap them both in p tags, and set `word-break` to `break-all`, and the `width` to `1px`.

A hacky solution, but one that works!

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/CUadz/), otherwise, I don't believe there is a cross-browser solution unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i also have to center them which doesnt seem to be possible with this.